# pda's seeds comes with u32.to_be_bytes(), how do I use ts to find the corresponding pda

Tags: anchor, solana-program, web3.js

**My Accounts:**

```
#[derive(Accounts)]
#[instruction(prize_index: u32)]
pub struct AddPrize<'info> {
    #[account(
        mut,
        constraint = raffle.creator == *creator.key,
    )]
    pub raffle: Account<'info, Raffle>,
    #[account(
        init,
        seeds = [raffle.key().as_ref(), PRIZE_PDA_SEED.as_ref(), &prize_index.to_be_bytes()],
        bump,
        payer = creator,
        token::mint = prize_mint,
        token::authority = raffle,
    )]
    pub prize: Account<'info, TokenAccount>,
    #[account(mut)]
    pub creator: Signer<'info>,
    #[account(mut)]
    pub from: Account<'info, TokenAccount>,
    pub prize_mint: Account<'info, Mint>,
    pub system_program: Program<'info, System>,
    pub token_program: Program<'info, Token>,
    pub rent: Sysvar<'info, Rent>,
}
```

**prize_index i set 1, but i can't find the pda with ts.**

```
const [prziePDA] = await anchor.web3.PublicKey.findProgramAddress([
  raffle_pda_address.toBuffer(),
  utf8.encode('prize'),
  new Uint8Array([0,0,0,1])
],program.programId)
```

**Is the new Uint8Array([0,0,0,1]) written incorrectly?**

How should I go about setting the param？

Comment: i find this     console.log("toArray: ", new anchor.BN(1).toArray("be", 4)); it can work!!!!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do it is to take a BN and convert it to lower endian bytes

```
let thisU32 = new anchor.BN("1");
let thisPda = PublicKey.findProgramAddressSync(
        [
          thisU32.toBuffer("le", 4),
        ],
        PROGRAM_ID
      )[0]
```

In `thisU32.toBuffer("le", 4)`,

- `le` indicates lower endian bytes and can be changed to `be` if desired, although (i think) the convention in solana land is to use lower endian.
- `4` indicates the number of bytes the number should take up. A u32 takes up 4 bytes of space, but a u64 would take up 8 bytes, a u8 only 1 byte and so on.

Comment: yes it can work, i think all the number should use BN.